# Login google account without openID

Tags: google-apps

Can I make a login form on my outside website that would allow users to login to our Google App? Is there an other possibility than using OpenID?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that without open id,but for that you must have user-id and password of both ie your website and his/her's google user-id and password.
Then you just have to pass userid and password to google as url and u have to store session.